# Surface Area/Volume Problem

Tags: volume

A Chocolate Jelly Bean manufacturer decided to produce Jelly Bean Balls(spheres) coated in chocolate. The machine produces 2.5m^3 of Jelly Bean and then splits it into 100000 balls and passes them to another machine to be coated in 2ml of chocolate.

Find:
a) The radius of each ball(with and without chocolate)

b) Find the total volume of chocolate needed to cover all Jelly Bean Balls

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've attempted to find the volume of one ball but attempts have proved fruitless.

Comment: Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What is the volume of a ball? What is the radius so the the sum of the volumes of $100000$ would be $2.5$

Comment: I already have this info though

Comment: So you are taking 2.5 m^3 of Jelly Bean and DIVIDING it evenly into 100000 pieces, how much is in each piece?

Comment: Each one would have 0.000025m^3

Comment: I got a radius of 1.81 cm

Comment: Can someone help me find b)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Now that you have the volume of one ball, use the formula linking the radius of a sphere to its volume to find the radius.  Then find the surface area of the sphere from that formula and the radius you know.  The thickness of chocolate is the volume of chocolate divided by this area (very close).

Comment: Is the radius without the chocolate 1.81 cm?

Comment: What is the formula that links?

Comment: You have $V=\frac 43 \pi r^3$ for the volume, $A=4 \pi r^2$ for the area.  I get $0.842$ for the radius.

Comment: That's gotta be wrong

Comment: I keep getting 1.81

Comment: I think you are doing 25÷4÷3÷π and then the cube root of that whole  answer instead of doing 25÷4/3(as a fraction) ÷π and a cube root of that

Comment: You are correct.  I dropped the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Convert 2ml to m^3 and add it to the volume of small jelly and equate it with 4/3*pi*r^3 to find r after coating.

Total volume is simply no. Of jelly balls * vol. Of chocolate needed for one jelly.